# Get HTML table without id in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am scrapping the following page: https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pp/EstadisticasSAEEPortal/Paginas/TIPasivaDepositoEmpresa.aspx?tip=C

The first problem is that the table that I want has no id, so I use class name.
[image html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuG2T.png)

I wanna extract all the info from the selected table. The problem is that when I scrap it using selenium I do find the table but I can't access its body or childs.

Here is my python code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome( ChromeDriverManager().install() )
url = "https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pp/EstadisticasSAEEPortal/Paginas/TIPasivaDepositoEmpresa.aspx?tip=C"

wd = webdriver.Chrome( ChromeDriverManager().install() )
wd.maximize_window()
wd.get(url)

table_path = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("APLI_tabla")

innerhtml = table_path.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

The code above outputs the following error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

This is the specific table I want:
[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, and things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to wait for the element to be loaded (clickable) in page, before locating them. Something like below will grab all tables from the page and print them as dataframes, just pick the one you need. Setup is for linux, but you can adapt it to your own, just pay attention to imports, and to the code after the browser is getting the url:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pp/EstadisticasSAEEPortal/Paginas/TIPasivaDepositoEmpresa.aspx?tip=C' 
browser.get(url)

tables = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table")))
print(len(tables))
for table in tables:
    
#     print(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    print(df)
    print('__________________')
```

This will print out all the tables as dataframes:

```
15
[]
__________________
[                                                           0
0  TASA DE INTERÉS PROMEDIO DEL SISTEMA DE CAJAS MUNICIPALES]
__________________
[                            0       1      2   3   4
0  Ingrese fecha: 2022  Junio     NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1  Ingrese fecha: 2022  Junio     NaN    NaN NaN NaN
2              Ingrese fecha:  2022.0  Junio NaN NaN,                             0       1      2   3   4
0  Ingrese fecha: 2022  Junio     NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1              Ingrese fecha:  2022.0  Junio NaN NaN,                 0     1      2   3   4
0  Ingrese fecha:  2022  Junio NaN NaN]
__________________
[                            0       1      2   3   4
0  Ingrese fecha: 2022  Junio     NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1              Ingrese fecha:  2022.0  Junio NaN NaN,                 0     1      2   3   4
0  Ingrese fecha:  2022  Junio NaN NaN]
__________________
```

Comment: thank you so much that is really useful, but I have a problem because the table that I want is inside other tables in the html, that is why I used the class name. Also the date that I am using is 2010 - octubre and the table is different for that specific date. I tried to change the code: tables = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"APLI_tabla"))) instead of tables = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "table"))) but it didn't work  :(

Comment: There is no `<table<` element with that class in page. That class, `APLI_tabla` appears for some `<div>` elements. If you use that selector, it should work (I mean, you can print the elements in the terminal). What particular table are you trying to grab? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I just posted it in the question above :)

Comment: I suspect that table is table[5] from tables. You can print them all out with `for table in tables:
    print(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))` and inspect each one of them. Once you found it, then you can isolate it and extract the data you need from them.